# neural network deconvolution filters

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I understand the concept of convolution.
Let's say that my input dimension is `3 x 10 x 10`

And if I say that I will have 20 activation maps and a filter size of 5, I will end up with 20 different filters for my layer, each with the dimension of `(3 x 5 x 5)`

My output will therefor be `(20 x ? x ?)`. I Put a "?" there, because it obviously depends on the filter stride etc.

---

Now I wanted to implement deconvolution but I am stuck at the following point:

For the following questions, let's assume that the input size for the deconvolution is `(5 x 8 x 8)`,

1. If we think about a filter in 3 dimensions. Can I choose any depth for the filter?
2. How would the effect of the amount of filters (amount of activation maps) work with deconvolution? Do I only have one filter?
3. How does the input depth (5) come into play. Would the output depth be equal to        
    (filter depth) * (input depth) ?

I am trying to find the symmetry to forward convolution but I do not understand how to use the amount of activation maps in deconvolution.

I am very thankful for any help.

Comment: Does https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/6107/8820 help you?